# how to remove or customize main menu items in Eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-luna

I have an RCP Eclipse Application based on Luna release. There are standard menu in this application. For example Help. I would like to change behavior of Help->Help Contents menu item. I would like to bind my command with this menuy item and show help document for main application. I can easy add new menu item to main menu and configure these one. But can I customize default ones

Comment: Are you using your own `ActionBarAdvisor`?

Comment: I don't use this one

Comment: You can suppress menu items using the `org.eclipse.ui.activities` extension point. Changing what an existing menu item does probably requires writing your own `ActionBarAdvisor` class.